# Regex pattern not matching for integers followed by strings

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex that would start with a integer number and then it might have a colon followed by a string. For example, it should pass for:

- `123`
- `123:e43e`
- `123:444+:343`

I tried using the regex as:

```
String timeZoneRegex = "^\\d+[:(=[a-zA-Z+-:0-9]+)]*";
```

This does not work; appreciate any help here.

Comment: `\\d` means *a backslash followed by the literal character `d`*. Did you mean `\d`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo - This user is probably using Java, where escaping the backslash is appropriate.

Comment: Hi,
This was really helpful.
But suppose there is this use case
the pattern could be either matching
123::abc
123:123
123:123:abc

if we tokenize this with colon as a separator,
meaning the first value before colon should always be present, the second depends on 3rd, either the 2nd or 3rd should be present and having both present is acceptable too.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that some regexp features depend on the regexp engine, but try with:

```
\d+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\-+]+)*
```

I've given a look to your express, you've made some mistake, maybe the most relevat one is the use of embeded [], you should know that inside the squared brackets the behaviour of symbols intepretation is a little different. This is a very [good source](http://www.regular-expressions.info) if you want to learn them. Cheers.